# Add a dependency based on some conditions in AspNetCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to add a dependency if some condition is met, but to test the condition I need to make use of `IServiceProvider`. Is there a good way to do it?

Here is my code but for sure this does not work properly for many reasons but thats what I have achieved so far:

Also I don't want to rebuild the `IServiceCollection` twice!

```
public static IServiceCollection AddWithCondition<TInterface, TImplementation>(
    this IServiceCollection collection, 
    Func<IServiceProvider, bool> validateFunc,
    ServiceLifetime lifetime,
    Func<IServiceProvider, TImplementation> factory)
    where TImplementation :  class
{ 
    collection.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(TInterface), p => validateFunc(p) ? factory(p) : default(TImplementation), lifetime));
    var descriptorToRemove = collection.FirstOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(TInterface) && d.ImplementationInstance == default);
    if (descriptorToRemove != null)
        collection.Remove(descriptorToRemove);
    return collection;
}
```

Comment: "this does not work properly for many reasons", you need to be explicit about those reasons.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to conditionally register the dependency, instead of just not injecting it where it isn't needed? That seems like it might lend itself to problems when people try to use it throughout the application.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto one reason was for example Autofac throws an exception if it find a null value for the implementation

Comment: Well, `default(TImplementation)` means `null`, what are you going to do with a `null`?

Comment: @Dortimer I register 3 implementations and inject an IEnumerable<MyInterface> in a class, in there I have a foreach -> doSomething, one of the implementation should not execute doSomething method in case a condition is met in startup, thats why I need to exclude it

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto remove it in the next step basically, as you can see I only register a null value because I need the IServiceProvider for the validateFunc

Comment: If a condition is met at startup that means you would only want to inject two implementations of `MyInterface` instead of three, then only register two instead of three. You almost certainly control what's going on at startup, so you shouldn't need to go back and inspect the service registrations. Is there some odd edge case where you don't or can't know what was registered?

Comment: @ScottHannen the condition needs IServiceProvider to be used because its not just a value in appSettings, its basically something taken from a web service. so I have to say if IServiceProvider.GetService<MyWebService>().IsValid => then register the interface, as you know you dont have IServiceProvider in startup without rebuilding the iServiceCollection, its more complicated than this but just as an example why I need the IServiceProvider

Comment: If it's an actual call to the web service then I would make that call independently of registering that service with the `IServiceCollection`. You can call the web service *without* resolving it from the `ServiceProvider` and then you know which other dependencies to resolve.

Comment: This is a sign of unclear focus in your application domain. You *know* what dependencies your application has. If you don't, then your application is likely trying to do too much/take on roles it's not actually suited for.

Comment: Class dependencies are normally a static aspect of a design, so how they are set up is a decision taken right at the beginning of your design with no conditionality normally. I agree with @ChrisPratt that this is a code smell that you have to establish different dependencies based on some logic test.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be applying domain logic in your application startup/configuration phase which is, as pointed out in the comments, a code smell. I suggest you refactor your application to use the factory pattern to create the instance(s) of the requested services. The factory can utilize dependency injection itself to perform the conditional logic. For example:

The services:

```cs
public interface IService { }

public class FooService : IService { }

// And more implementations of IService...
```

The service factory:

```cs
public interface IServiceFactory
{
    IEnumerable<IService> GetServices();
}

public class ServiceFactory : IServiceFactory
{
    public ServiceFactory(MyWebservice myWebservice) { }

    public IEnumerable<IService> GetServices()
    {
        // Use MyWebservice to conditionally create the desired IService instances
        // or use any other type of logic.
    }
}
```

After you add the `IServiceFactory` to your dependency injection container, you can inject it and use it to resolve the `IService` instances:

```cs
public class SomeController
{
    public SomeController(IServiceFactory serviceFactory) { }

    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var services = _serviceFactory.GetServices();
        // Do something with the created IService instances...
    }
}
```